# SSIS Data Profiling Task - Not showing all in Data Profile Outputs

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, data-profiling

Chose following request for Data Profiling Task in SSDT 2017. But, it's only showing NullRationReq in output and NOT the other requests. I tried few times, and when checked profiler output xml - in the DataProfileOutput node it only has NullRatioReq1, trying to see why it is not showing output for other requests in profiler.

[image]

Below is profiler output and xml snippet

[image]

xml snippet

[image]